# Распознавание капчи

Tags: python, captcha, распознавание-символов

Получаю изображение капчи, хочу распознать её с помощью easyocr или tesseract.

`EasyOcr` хорошо справляется с задачей, но в некоторых отдельных случаях срабатывает неверно (вместо `Z` обнаруживает `2`, или вместо `5` обнаруживает `S`)

Оригинальное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убираем цвет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаемся убрать точки фильтром:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, буквы сильно похудели из-за фильтра. Я думаю, что если убрать точки другим способом, то распознавание станет получше.

Капча представлена всегда в таком виде (4 символа, в рандомных цветах и с рандомными точками)
Так же есть доступ ко всем используемым буквам (jpg, либо bmp изображения)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, **как правильно реализовать распознавание капчи**?

Можно другими методами, главное что бы результат был приближен к 100%

Код не мой, он предоставлен добровольно в моё пользование:

```py
def erode(cycles, image):
    for _ in range(cycles):
        image = image.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(3))
    return image


def get_captcha_screenshot():
    # Сделать скриншот с экрана в нужной области
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(all_screens=True)
    screenshot = screenshot.crop((664, 718, 767, 746))
    #screenshot = screenshot.crop((904, 898, 1007, 926))
    screenshot.save("screenshot3.png")
    
    # Создаём чистый квадрат
    im = Image.open("screenshot3.png")
    im = im.convert("P")
    im2 = Image.new("P", im.size, 255)
    im = im.convert("P")

    temp = {}
    
    # Удаляем все синие пиксели
    for x in range(im.size[1]):
        for y in range(im.size[0]):
            pix = im.getpixel((y, x))
            temp[pix] = pix
            if pix == 225:
                im2.putpixel((y, x), 0)

    im2.save("screenshot3.gif")
    im = Image.open("screenshot3.gif")
    im = im.convert('RGB')
    
    # Удаляем лишние пиксели
    step_1 = erode(1, im)
    step_1.save("screenshot3.jpg")
```

**UPD**: Дополнительные изображения капчи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по хорошему вам нужно капнуть в сторону OCR систем

Comment: @acinit easyocr и tesseract они и есть, просто они справляются на 99%, а 1% в моей задаче очень критичен. Может быть каким-то образом можно научить их распознавать конкретные буквы? (у меня есть файлы букв, которые используются)

Comment: В таком случае рекомендую вам смириться, так как от ошибок никуда не деться, даже по вероятности того, что сама каптча может сгенерироваться абсолютно нечитаемой (вылезание буквы С за правый край может расцениваться как О, например)

Comment: Можете добавить еще три-четыре изображения капчей?

Comment: @Acinit символы никогда не наплывают друг на друга.

Comment: @СергейКох Добавил

Comment: я попиксельно не сравнивал, но похоже, что тут все буквы идентичные и на них наложен шум из точек. Нужно просто убрать эти цветные точки и получатся обычные черные буквы. И их можно будет хоть распознавать, хоть с эталоном сравнивать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, так и есть, даже есть эталон в виде отдельных букв, как правильно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью `pytesseract` и `numpy`. Для того, чтоб распознавались символы более четко надо подготовить изображение. Убрать шумовые пиксели и сделать черные символы на белом фоне. Пиксели, у которых нет трех соседей - убираем.

P.S. При таком удалении обнулялись угловые внешние пиксели, а они скорее всего нужны `pytesseract` для более точного определения символов. Поэтому я изменил  код, и теперь обнуляются пиксели только у которых нет двух соседей. Ошибка с пятым символом ушла.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

# Запускаем pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Открываем картинку и конвертируем её в оттенки серого.
im = Image.open(r"ze5t.png")
im = im.convert("L")

# Инвертируем картинку, чтоб фон был черным.
im_invert = ImageOps.invert(im)

# Создаем матрицу инвертированного изображения.
np_invert = np.array(im_invert)

# Создаем матрицы для соседей каждой клетки.
w = np.zeros(np_invert.shape, bool)
e = np.zeros(np_invert.shape, bool)
n = np.zeros(np_invert.shape, bool)
s = np.zeros(np_invert.shape, bool)

w[:, 1:] = np.logical_or(w[:, 1:], np_invert[:, :-1] > 0)  # слева
e[:, :-1] = np.logical_or(e[:, :-1], np_invert[:, 1:] > 0)  # справа
n[1:, :] = np.logical_or(n[1:, :], np_invert[:-1, :] > 0)  # выше
s[:-1, :] = np.logical_or(s[:-1, :], np_invert[1:, :] > 0)  # ниже

# # Удаляем пиксели у которых нет трех соседей.
# np_invert[~(w & e & n) & ~(w & e & s) & ~(w & n & s) & ~(e & n & s)] = 0

# Удаляем пиксели у которых нет двух соседей.
np_invert[~(w & e) & ~(w & n) & ~(w & s) & ~(e & n) & ~ (e & s) & ~ (n & s)] = 0

# Инвертируем матрицу и делаем черно-белой, чтоб черные цифры были на белом фоне.
np_result = 255 - np_invert
np_result[np_result < 255] = 0

# Выбираем язык и, что данные будут одной строкой текста.
custom_config = r'-l eng --psm 7'
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(np_result, config=custom_config)
print(data)
```

Еще хорошо отработал вариант с cv2. Где-то я скачал с английского `stackoverflow`, сейчас не нашел источник.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('a2vh.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph open to remove noise and invert image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
invert = 255 - opening


# Perform text extraction
custom_config = r'-l eng --psm 7'
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, config=custom_config)
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Источник - ответ [nathancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745519/use-pytesseract-ocr-to-recognize-text-from-an-image#:%7E:text=53-,Here%27s%20a%20simple,-approach%20using%20OpenCV).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Тессеракт сыпется на капче HLFP, получается результат HLFEP. В общем думаю сейчас о том, как удалить все лишние точки, разделить буквы по пикселям и сравнить их с эталоном ( как предложил @Эникейщик ), думаю это будет лучшим вариантом, ну, либо дообучить нейросеть.

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn    Да, есть такая проблема в тессеракте вставлять альтернативные символы. Рекомендуют " Для случайной последовательности символов вам необходимо:
1. Отключите словарь.
2. Точная настройка английской модели с похожими изображениями.
Если у вас есть вопросы по тонкой настройке, воспользуйтесь форумом." https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1465

Comment: можно разбить изображение на символы и использовать опцию --psm 10, тогда в ответе будет ровно 4 символа.

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn Я немного изменил код, ошибка ушла, попробуйте.

Comment: В общем, я написал свой генератор капчи и стал тестировать это. Все способы моментально посыпались, я обрезал каждую букву по размеру, и стал сравнивать с помощью OpenCV. Примерно 10 минут уже работает, ни одной нераспознанной капчи.  Генерирую примерно 5 капч в секунду, так что хватит примерно на 150 часов работы при условии, что капча раз в 3 минуты появляется

Comment: Образец разместите, пожалуйста, на котором посыпалось.

Comment: @СергейКох выложил код генератора на github, если интересно разобраться [тык](https://github.com/1WTFIsGoingOn/Captcha-Generator)